# How to grep a number following a keyword from a textfile?

Tags: linux, regex, grep

How to `grep` the member id `X01930` from the following file?

```
Blah Blah ... Blah
Blah Blah Blah ... Member ID: X01930 Blah Blah ... Blah
... 
Blah Blah ... Blah
```

The string `Member ID:` is usually there, and the member id is a single string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo 'Blah Blah Blah ... Member ID: X01930 Blah Blah ... Blah' | grep -oP '(?<=Member ID: )[^ ]+'
X01930
```

This uses `grep`'s `P`erl regexp syntax and prints `o`nly the matching part.

The expression matches any contiguous sequence of non-space characters that is preceded ([positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) by `Member ID:`.

Answer (score 0):

You need more tools than `grep` alone to get it. For example, if your `grep` supports the `-o` option, you can use `cut`:

```
grep -o 'Member ID: .*' INPUT | cut -d' ' -f3
```